# Can I pass all of my existing env vars to an image without declaring them indv?

Tags: docker, docker-for-mac

Currently my run command looks like this...

```
docker run -e DB_URL=$DB_URL -e DB_PORT=$DB_PORT ... <image name>
```

This works but not very scalable. Is there a way to just pass all configured env vars to the container without declaring each one?

I am using OSX and these are set in a .bash_profile.

Comment: What about a shell script to gather the needed env variables (set, grep, ...), build the run command string and fire it up?

Comment: Sure but that kind of isn't the point, I would rather have a less hacky solution. What happens if I add env vars and don't remember to update etc.

Comment: With Docker Compose you can specify your env variables in the Compose file, or you can specify an `env_file` that contains all your environment variables. I would suggest go this way.

Comment: Right the env_file thing seems the closes so far like env_file=~/.bash_profile. But this could be an issue with windows or other OS images. So I would like to essentially just copy over all env vars (or at least unless blacklisted)

Answer (score 2):

`env > envFile && docker run --env-file=envFile alpine env`

However I would not recommend doing this as this will pass even un-necessary info to docker container.
And you should rather use a compose file or maybe even a simple script to only pass in variables that are actually needed. 
This might even mess with the shell inside of a container for things like prompts and locales etc.

Comment: Pretty much the same answer Mark gave, up voted because it works but not the clean solution I am looking for...

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately, the best option is to explicitly list the vars you want to pass. There should only be a finite number of them, they shouldnt change often, and this solution is more robust and more secure.

Note that you can simplify your example. If you want to pass in a defined var with its current value, just name the var instead of setting it:

```
docker run -e DB_URL -e DB_PORT ... <image name>
```